# How to do an event listener with current functions?

Tags: javascript, html

My understanding of an event handler is that it allows the event handler that takes an existing function and allows you to do something with it like a click or some kind of event

What I am trying to do is when the = button is pressed on my calculator it uses the `calculation function` and takes the `if-else` statements and applies it to the `=` sign. For example, if the user clicks `1 + 1` the `=` sign should add them together and give the answer.

```js
/*********************
Setting up varlaibles*
**********************/

let result;
let num1;
let num2;


/*****************************************
Function for numbers to display on screen*
******************************************/

function buttonPress(numbers) {

  let input = document.querySelector('.answer').innerText.split('\n').join('') + numbers
  let display = document.querySelector('.answer').innerHTML = input
  console.log(`${typeof display} ${display}`)

  if (display.length >= 21) {

    for (let i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
      document.querySelector('.answer').style.marginTop = -i + "px";
    }
  }
}

  /***********************************
Function for calculation of numbers*
************************************/

function calculation(buttonPress){

switch(numbers){
    case "/":
        numbers / numbers;
        break;
    case "*":
        numbers * numbers;
        break;
    case "+":
        numbers + numbers;
        break;
    case "-":
        numbers - numbers;
        break;
    case "%":
        numbers % numbers;
        break;     
        default:
}
  
buttonPress()
}
```

```html
<div class="answer"></div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-op clear" onclick="buttonPress('C')">C</button>
    <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('()')">()</button>
    <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('%')">%</button>
    <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('/')">/</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(1)">1</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(2)">2</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(3)">3</button>
    <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('X')">x</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(4)">4</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(5)">5</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(6)">6</button>
    <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('+')">+</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(7)">7</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(8)">8</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(9)">9</button>
    <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('-')">-</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="col-num" id="border-left" onclick="buttonPress(0)">0</button>
    <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress('.')">.</button>
    <button class="col-eq-end" id="border-right" onclick="buttonPress('=')">=</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

The outcome should be with `addEventListener` that if the user uses operators to with the numbers the = sign should give the answer.

Comment: Off topic - But you should definitely use a `switch` statement in `calculation`

Comment: Also, please add your minimal html to your question.

Comment: It looks like you can quite easily make a runnable example and demonstrate what part you're stuck on. You have styling in there and selectors (all strangely selecting the same element) so it's hard to imagine what you're trying to do/where you're going wrong

Comment: You can use anonymus function (so `plusButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){calculation('to')})`). If you want to use the simple function, you can use (in theory) `plusButton.addEventListener('click',calculate,'to')` ``

Comment: Thanks, guys, I updated the code with a code snippet, so you can see how it is working. I am focusing only on how to make the numbers calculate on = button and it gives an answer

Comment: @AspiringDev You should remove the CSS snippet, it has nothing to do with the question - which revolves around JS (and possibly HTML).

Comment: @AmitBeckenstein left the HTML and js in there as the js is using the buttons from HTML and the class of answer from there too.